# How do I add an account to a domain?

Tags: cmd.exe, administrator, multiple-computers

I am in at a business with multiple computers and a domain that organizes everything. I am trying to add a new account to the domain using the SYSTEM account that is pre logged into the computer using CMD. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You need to be an Administrator on the domain in order to add an account to the domain.  The local System account doesn’t have the necessary permissions to add an account to the domain

Comment: Orecisely. You are trying to add an account to the domain. This is managed by the domain controller. You need an account with rights on the domain, not a local account.

Answer (score 2):

To add an AD user from the Command Prompt, use `dsadd`, for example:

```
dsadd user “cn=John Doe,cn=Users,dc=ad,dc=contoso,dc=com” -samid jdoe -upn jdoe@ad.contoso.com -fn John -ln Doe -display "John Doe" -disabled no -pwd “PassWord!@” -mustchpwd yes
```

More information about the dsadd command can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731279(v=ws.11).aspx).

Domain accounts can also be added using the **Active Directory Users and Computers** MMC console snap-in. It's installed by default on all domain controllers and can be found in the Start Menu.

Once in the ADUC snap-in, simply right click in the container or Organizational Unit where you want to create the user and choose New User from the menu.

To add an account you must be a member of the Account Operators domain security group. By default, only domain Administrators are members of this group. (It's also possible to delegate to a user the authority to create accounts in specific OUs, but that's outside the scope of this answer.)